# Как отменить удаление одного из файлов в одном из прошлых локальных коммитов

Tags: git

Локальная ветка. Кое-что добавил, изменил, плюс случайно удалил один файлик. Закоммитил.

Потом ещё кое-что написал, опять закоммитил.

Ничего не пушил. Т.е. и ветка и все коммиты - локальные.
Мне надо в первом коммите отменить удаление этого файла. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Для изменения коммита, который не является последним, существует интерактивный rebase. https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Git'е нет специального инструмента для редактирования истории, но вы можете использовать `rebase` для перемещения ряда коммитов на то же самое место, где они были изначально, а не куда-то в другое место. Интерактивное перемещение можно запустить, добавив опцию `-i` к `git rebase` В вашем случаем нужно использовать команду `git rebase -i HEAD~2`.

Стоит заметить что все коммиты в диапазоне HEAD~2..HEAD будут переписаны вне зависимости от того, меняли ли вы в них сообщение или нет. Команда выведет коммиты в обратном порядке.  Они начнаются с коммита, который вы указали.Вам надо отредактировать сценарий так, чтобы он останавливался на коммитах, которые вы хотите отредактировать. Чтобы сделать это, замените слово pick на слово edit для каждого коммита, на котором сценарий должен остановиться.

Когда вы сохраните и выйдете из редактора, Git откатит вас назад к последнему коммиту в списке и выкинет вас в командную строку.

Дальше используйте `git commit --amend` для редактирования коммита и для завершения редактированя коммита используйте `git rebase --continue`(возможно попросит мерж).

Comment: Борис, Илья, спасибо. Получилось. Правда я не всё в консоли делал, к примеру revert удаления я через IDEA провёл.

Answer (score 0):

Второй вариант решения: это --fixup и --autosquash.
Более подробно [здесь](http://fle.github.io/git-tip-keep-your-branch-clean-with-fixup-and-autosquash.html).