# Как отменить удаление локальной ветки Git

Tags: android, android-studio, bitbucket, git-branch

Пользуюсь `bitbucket`. Пишу в `AndroidStudio`.

Решил проредить количество неактуальных веток. Как правило удаляю и локальные и удаленные ветки (чтобы хвостов не было на битбакете).

И как результат в общем скопе опрометчиво удалил одну нужную ветку.

В инете нахожу только как отменить последний коммит или мердж. Но не удаление ветки.

В вопросе [Как отменить удаление одного из файлов в одном из прошлых локальных коммитов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/636033/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) описано варианты возврата к изначальному коммиту на существующей ветке. У меня же ветка убита.

Как воскресить убитую ветку?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отменить удаление одного из файлов в одном из прошлых локальных коммитов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/636033/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%88%d0%bb%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: @VerNick К сожалению не дубликат. Там о ветке существующей и как вернуться к изначальному коммиту. Я же свою ветку снес напрочь ((

Comment: Случайно снесли?

Comment: @VerNick Спросонку, не выспавшись как всегда, решил сдуру почистить хлам. Дочистился ((

Comment: Кода много было? Чем больше кода, тем больнее.

Comment: @VerNick Немного, но там фикс один был, над которым промаялся несколько часов. Не охота снова с тем же возиться и время терять. Тем более что писал то я его дней 5 назад, а после того еще пару веток правил, так что инфа уже немного призабылась.

Comment: Удачи! Ответ подошел?

Comment: @VerNick В предположительном вопросе-дубликате? Там только почерпнул ход мысли как переключиться на старый коммит. За это тоже спасибо)

Comment: Я про этот вопрос:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если знаете sha:

```
git checkout -b <branch> <sha>
```

Если нет - попробуйте найти её через

```
git reflog
```

Comment: С `git reflog` нашел свою ветку ))) Спасибо!